# Profiling nodejs with v8

Tags: node.js, profiling, v8

I have a node application which i want to profile using the node profiler.

So first i ran:

```
node --prof v8test.js
```

Then, I downloaded the v8 tools

```
svn checkout http://v8.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ v8;
make dependencies;
make native;
```

Then tried to analyze the file created (v8.log)

```
tools/linux-tick-processor ../v8.log
```

But i get a lot of:

```
Code move event for unknown code: 0x289dd8475560
Code move event for unknown code: 0x289dd84758e0
Code move event for unknown code: 0x289dd8479280
Code move event for unknown code: 0x289dd8482980
Code move event for unknown code: 0x289dd84c2a80
line 718730: unknown code state: undefined
line 718731: unknown code state: undefined
line 739575: unknown code state: undefined
line 739577: unknown code state: undefined
```

Can anybody help me figure out what's going on ?

Comment: Not an answer, but Ben Noordhuis is helping me sort out the same problem : 
https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/nodejs/4NMoiPd2K6s

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The log file format seems to change quite frequently, so you need to make sure that you are using the right version of v8. For instance, if the profile log was generated with node v0.10.18, you have to analyse it with the tick processor for v8 version 3.14.5. To find out which version of v8 a given version of node is built on, you can check `deps/v8/ChangeLog` in the node source distribution (node's own changelog seems to be a little unreliable in this respect).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're not running a 64 bit version of node with a 32 bit version of the profiling tools or vice versa I had a similar problem when I did that by accident.

Comment: @Viclib - From the node site download either 32 or 64 bit version then when you compile the v8 tools follow their build instructions to build them for a 32 bit or 64 bit environment. I found getting 32 bit node +  building a 32 bit version of the profiling tools was easiest to do.

Answer (score 0):

One more option to profile a node application is to use VTune Amplifier instead internal V8 profiler embedded in Node.js. In this case you will see how the performance metrics are distributed through the source code of your function. V8 profile can't do that now. Look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21571145/profiling-javascript-code-on-nodejs-possible-approaches?rq=1) to see how you do that.