# Compiling nodejs with vtune and jitprofiling.h support

Tags: javascript, node.js, intel-vtune

My only purpose is do profiling of JavaScript code under Node.js with vTune.

I tried to follow the steps that appear under this post: [Profiling Nodejs with vTune](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21571145/profiling-javascript-code-on-nodejs-possible-approaches/21603144#21603144), but I have no luck.

I use Debian 7 x86_64, and my version of vTune Amplifier XE is 2015 (evaluation mode). The modules are loaded with the `service sep3_15 start` on boot, and I can see them with `lsmod`. Also, I build the sample `jitprofiling` project provided with vTune, and it works (I can see the dynamic content). So, my problem is building Node.js with vTune support.

If I do the above steps, and I just change `vcbuild.bat nosign` with `./configure` and `make`, I get an error "../src/node.cc:22:67: fatal error: v8-vtune.h: No such file or directory", and the only solution that continues compiling correctly is by adding also the next line in `node.gyp`:

```
  'include_dirs': [
    // ...
    'deps/v8/src/third_party/vtune',
    // ...
```

It is the only way to fetch the includes (`v8-vtune.h`) and compile node.

But when importing with vTune Amplifier I cannot see the `Dynamic code` nor the sources of JS.

I tried many different things, like building node for debugging with `./configure --build` and even `./configure --debug --gdb`, and then forcing to execute the `node` binary from `out/Debug/node`, instead from `out/Release/node`. I can see that it has the symbol definitions (`strings node | wc -l` is much bigger than in the Release version) because It doesn't throw a warning when profiling with vTune. And although I can see all node source code, I cannot see the `Dynamic code`.

I even tried to force variables `gdbjit=on` and `vtunejit=on` under `deps/v8/Makefile`

I tried with the nightly build 0.11.11 and with the latest 0.11.14.

I have no clue what to do.

EDIT: I was doing more compilations with different options (above mentioned). Finally, I can see how it works up to the 0.11.12 version, but no 0.11.13 nor 0.11.14.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VTune support in V8 targeted by node.js 0.11.13 was broken due to the changes in V8. It was resolved in the latest V8 version.
For node.js 0.11.13 you need to fix it manually:

1. Follow this instructions [Profiling Nodejs with vTune](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21571145/profiling-javascript-code-on-nodejs-possible-approaches/21603144#21603144). I assume that you have already done it.
2. Fix the broken VTune support:

[nodejs-v0.11.13]\deps\v8\include\v8.h file:
replace

```
Handle<Script> script;
```

with

```
Handle<UnboundScript> script;
```

[nodejs-v0.11.13]\deps\v8\src\log.cc file: in "void JitLogger::LogRecordedBuffer(...)" function, replace

```
event.script = ToApiHandle<v8::UScript>(script_handle);
```

with

```
event.script = ToApiHandle<v8::UnboundScript>(script_handle);
```

[nodejs-v0.11.13]\deps\v8\src\third_party\vtune\vtune-jit.cc file: in "void VTUNEJITInterface::event_handler(const v8::JitCodeEvent* event)" function, replace

```
Handle<Script> script = event->script;
```

with

```
Handle<UnboundScript> script = event->script;
```

It should help.